# storage migration check error: error="pq: permission denied for table vault_kv_store"

Tags: postgresql, hashicorp-vault, spring-cloud-vault-config, spring-vault

Here is my vault.config file.

```
ui = true

backend "postgresql" {
connection_url = "postgres://user:pwd@192.168.1.1:5432/vault?sslmode=disable"
}

listener "tcp" {
  address = "0.0.0.0:8200"
  tls_disable = 1
}

disable_mlock = true
```

I have also created table vault_kv_store and vault_ha_locks under public schema in the vault database as per [vault storage doc](https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/configuration/storage/postgresql).

We need help to fix this problem.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

you used a different user when you created the table, run the following command after connecting to the vault database:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO user;
```